# Jenkins declarative pipeline - settings stable/unstable threshold

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am working on a project with a `Jenkinsfile` setup. This project runs on a number of integration tests, some of which are expected to fail. We are fixing the tests ( or the implementation ) one by one, but in the meantime the jobs are marked as failed.

The relevant state snippet is

```
    stage ('Run ITs') {
        steps {
            sh 'SHOW_LOGS=0 ./compose/scripts/up-testing.sh'
            sh 'sleep 60'
            timeout (720) {
                sh './testing/scripts/run-its.sh'
            }
        }

        post {
            always {
                sh './testing/scripts/summarize-it-results.sh'
                junit 'testing/failsafe-resports/*.xml'
                sh './compose/scripts/killall.sh'
            }
    }
```

I'd like to set a threshold (T) on the number of failures + errors (F+E) and mark the build as unstable if we get `F+E <= T` and failed otherwise.

How can I do this with the Jenkins pipeline plugin?

Comment: Were you able to workaround this somehow?

Comment: @VadimKotov - no, issue is still open for me

Answer (score 2):

I think it is currently not possible with JUnit plugin "out-of-the-box". Here is the [corresponding issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2734) in Jenkins issue tracker.

Comment: Is this issue really related to the Pipeline plugin? As far as I can tell it is strictly refers to the JUnit plugin

Comment: @RobertMunteanu that's true, the field Component in this issue is set to "junit-plugin". But still, you cant set a threshold via pipeline script (and via free-style jobs too), because there is no support for that in junit plugin.